How to do Bayesian MCMC with Compositional Parameter Constraints
So I know that if you have parameter constraints and you were to do a random walk MH without them, you can use a truncated normal distribution as your proposal instead (and of course, this would be reflected in the Hasting ratio as symmetry is lost). But what if we are doing this for say, a 3-component Gaussian Mixture Model? What is the best way to constrain the first two proportion parameters to sum less than or equal to one? Of course, the third proportion parameter isn't a parameter to be solved, since it is a function of the first two.
Perhaps using a Dirichlet proposal? But then what do I do about the other parameters? They are not proportional.
Thanks.

I do not understand the difficulty: the proposal kernel can be supported by the actual parameter space, which is the product of the 3D-simplex for the weights, of $\mathbb R^3$ for the means, and $\mathbb R_+^3$ for the variances or standard deviations.

See, e.g., Chapter 6 of our book Bayesian essentials with R

Ah, okay thanks. I've never used multiple proposal distributions before (product of distributions).
